# submit form in ruby on rails where action is your full url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, post, iframe

So a follow up to this question: [getting bad request from ruby on rails ssl post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844277/getting-bad-request-from-ruby-on-rails-ssl-post).

I fixed that problem and I make the next step in the transaction no problem. The problem I am facing is that their response is sent to an iFrame as a hidden form on an html document. The form then posts to a url that I provide them.

I have tried giving them `localhost:3000/policies/complete` making a controller action and a route resource for the post but it doesn't ever show anything.
- It just says `javascript error unable to load resource: localhost:3000/policies/complete`

So then I tried just `/policies/complete` (with the coresponding method in my policies controller `complete`) but for some reason instead of posting to that action - it posted to `theirwebserver.com/policies/complete` which obviously doesn't exist.

So since it looks like I have to pass in a whole url for it to work correctly the form is going to look like: `<form method='Post' action='whatever whole url I give them'>`

The form looks like this:

```
<form name="frmReturn" method="Post" action="localhost:3000/policies/hosted_checkout_complete">
    <input name="PaymentID" type="hidden" value="the value you need really badly!">
    <input name="ReturnCode" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input name="ReturnMessage" type="hidden" value="Your transaction has been approved."> 
</form>
```

Tl:DC How do I set up my app to handle that?

I can request that they use `get` to send the information back to me. If that would be easier to set up and accept please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the protocol (either http:// or https://) to the front of the action=

```
<form name="frmReturn" method="Post" action="http://localhost:3000/policies/hosted_checkout_complete">
```

However, I would NOT recommend doing this... You have completely missed the point of Rails routing. You should be doing something like this:

```
<form name="frmReturn" method="Post" action="<%= resource_url %>">
```

Ideally, you'd use the Rails form builders:

```
<%= form_for :resource, :action => 'hosted_checkout_complete' do %>
```

Comment: you have missed the point of my question. The form is coming from a different site which they are putting in an iframe on my site. I have NO control over the form! I would LOVE to use rails helpers and do on a daily basis. The whole reason I am stuck right now is because I CAN'T USE RAILS HELPERS. (sorry for yelling/caps but I have been at this for 2 days that the api I am being forced to use is well.... yea)

Comment: And yet you still helped me out! thanks a bunch! I did need the http:// for it to resolve to the right host.