# PHP Evernote SDK TTransportException

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, evernote

In Ubuntu 12.04 the Evernote PHP SDK always gives an error:

`Uncaught TTransportException: exception 'TTransportException' with message 'THttpClient: Could not connect to sandbox.evernote.com:443/edam/user'`

I was able to fix this issue in my WAMP server by allowing the extension `php_openssl.dll`. But, had no success in Ubuntu 12.04 with `php_openssl.so`.

Any ideas about what the fix is?

Answer (score 0):

We're aware of a problem with our SSL endpoints and hope to have a patch soon: http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26978-ssl-handshake-problems/

Comment: Isn't https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1-4ubuntu5.3 a server side patch for this?