# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in UsersController#create (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, sendmail

I have seen a lot of StackOverFlow answer and posting this question again.
Raising problem while sending mail sometime it is working fine if i restart the server i am facing the problem again.

SMTP Settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address:              'smtp.1and1.com',
 port:                 25,
 domain:               'leotechnosoft.net',
 user_name:            'santoshk@leotechnosoft.net',
 password:             'password',
 openssl_verify_mode:  'none',
 authentication:       'plain',
 enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in UsersController#create

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol
```

I tired with changing the settings ssl true/false, tls true/false, open_ssl_verify_mode:none
enable_starttls_auto: true.

Please Explain me what is root cause for this problem and how can i resolve.

Ruby 1.9.3 (Actually the problem has raised after upgrading to ruby 2.1.2 and then its not working in 1.9.3 also)

Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to a known bug in ubuntu 12.04 when using openssl 1.0.1 as described in the last answer here:

[OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError Ubuntu 12.04 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847779/opensslsslsslerror-ubuntu-12-04-only)

You can find more information about the bug on Ubuntu's bug tracker https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371

Apparently, if you force the use of SSLv3, the error should disappear.

[Ruby SSL error - sslv3 alert unexpected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821051/ruby-ssl-error-sslv3-alert-unexpected-message)

You might also want to check out if `leotechnosoft.net` is blocking port 25 when using SSL as some hosting providers sometimes block port 25 by default. When you're using SSL try with port 465 instead.

Comment: This is unfortunate that using SSLv3 is the fix, as it is no longer to be trusted because of the POODLE vulnerability.

Comment: You're right... The vulnerability was found after my original post. I'll try to submit an updated answer as soon as I can get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same message using gmail smtp, but when i changed from "plain" to "login", the problem was solved.

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:                 587,
      domain:               'gmail.com',
      user_name:            'youremail@gmail.com',
      password:             'yourpassword',
      authentication:       :login
    }
```