# Is there a way to set the client hello in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, openssl, open-uri

I am writing a standalone script and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369962/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-unknown-state-unkn) addresses the problem I'm having, and like the original poster I attempted to use

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But I had no luck with that.

It is mentioned in one of the responses that you may be able change the program to send a different client hello. Is it possible to do this in a ruby script?

I am currently using ruby 2.0.0-1.9.5 and don't want to change my ruby version. 
If changing the client hello isn't possible, are there any gems which help with this problem?

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "set the client hello"?

Answer (score 1):

> OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
>
> But I had no luck with that.

That does not appear to make any sense. It appears you are assigning `VERIFY_NONE` to `VERIFY_PEER`. Those are OpenSSL constants, not variables. So you can't do that.

---

Those are OpenSSL context options. According to the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html), you need to set them with `verify_mode`:

> **verify_mode**
>
> Session verification mode.
>
> Valid modes are `VERIFY_NONE`, `VERIFY_PEER`, `VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE`, `VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT` and defined on OpenSSL::SSL

---

> It is mentioned in one of the responses that you may be able change the program to send a different client hello. Is it possible to do this in a ruby script?

There are two types of `ClientHello`s. One is the old SSL `ClientHello`, and the other is a TLS `ClientHello`. Because the original SSL specification did not have versioning  info, it was hard to tell which was being sent. As I understand it, a particular byte is examined to tell which is used. Some clients and servers still don't handle it well.

As far as I know, Ruby has a few options for the OpenSSL method. From the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html):

```
new => ctx
new(:TLSv1) => ctx
new("SSLv23_client") => ctx
```

You want to send a `ClientHello` which corresponds to OpenSSL's `SSLv23_method`. This affords most compatibility. However, it enables SSLv2 protocol and above (SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, and TLS1.2)

To remove the broken, weak and wounded protocols (like SSLv2 and SSLv3), you have to set some context options. Unfortunately, Ruby does not appear to offer `OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2` and other context options (or I could not find them). See [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550213/uninitialized-constant-opensslsslssl-op-sslv2-nameerror).

So I think you are stuck at the moment.