# Specify SSL version for Net::IMAP

Tags: ruby, email, ssl, imap

I am having issues with SSL when connecting to an IMAP server.

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

After some research, I found a solution to this in "[Ruby SSL error - sslv3 alert unexpected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821051/ruby-ssl-error-sslv3-alert-unexpected-message)", however, is there a way to force the SSL version for IMAP?

Comment: First, are you sure you're connecting to an SSL port?

Comment: Yes I am. I got it work though on an older version of ruby. 1.9.3p448, however with new versions of ruby I am still getting this error. What could this? Appreciate your help @Max